# Run HTML inside Script Tags Using EJS Template

Tags: node.js, express, video-streaming, livechat, simplewebrtc

I am trying to implement Video Streaming + Live Chat using Simple WebRTC. Here is the link to tutorial:

[Click here](https://www.sitepoint.com/webrtc-video-chat-application-simplewebrtc/)!

It works fine when i implement it in a fresh application using html extension. But i am working on some project and i need to embed this code inside my project which uses EJS templating.

Here are screenshots of what error it shows

Code
[image: Code]

Console Error
[image: Console Error]

I have tried using HTML template it works fine inside it but, not working inside EJS Template.
It is clear that i want ejs file to treat these script tags as html. Please help. Thanks in advance